# How to open a RAdWindow when i click on Radscheduler timeslot

Tags: radwindow, radscheduler

i am using the Radscheduler in that i want open the Radwindow when i click on Timeslot per a perticuler timeslot.Is it possible open the Radwindow in Rad scheduler ?Is possible please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to these controls: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scheduler-object.html then see the documentation at [Telerik RadScheduler ClientSide Events](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scheduler-client-side-programming-events.html), the [OnClientTimeSlotClick](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scheduler-onclienttimeslotclick.html) event